# Health Care Legal Parents But Prevent Representation

Tags: united-states, health

My father is catholic and doesn't believe in divorce which means although my parents haven't lived with each other for years they are legally married.

I am on their health care plan still but do not want one specific parent being able to be a health care info and be a contact for lots of reasons.  Is there a way to prevent this one parent from being a contact/legal representative for health reasons?

Comment: Are you over 21? Which parent is the primary health care person? Is that who you don't want to be a contact?

Comment: @mkennedy yes I am over 21.  Hmm I am not sure they both work.  I will check.

Comment: @mkennedy you mean over 15 - children in Australia are legally autonomous with respect to health care at 16.

Comment: @DaleM Where are you getting Australia from? I did default to USA (where over 18 could also matter).

Comment: @mkennedy  and why would you default to the USA? The OP doesn’t mention a jurisdiction

Comment: @DaleM because a majority of questions here are US-based and one of the popular tags on his profile is "united-states".

Comment: @mkennedy without a tag in the OP, that’s not an assumption you are entitled to make - jurisdiction free posts are open to any jurisdiction so if you assume one, you should state it.

Comment: @DaleM I shall attempt to be more precise when requesting further information from OPs. However, very few jurisdiction-free questions are answerable without making it a community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an adult for purposes of health care decision making, you can complete a health care power of attorney designating who can make decisions for you if you cannot, which you can share with your primary care provider, and you can advise your healthcare provider and insurer with whom they are authorized to share health care information. The insurance company probably has a form for that.

If you are not an adult for purposes of health care decision making, tough luck, you are stuck with what your parents decide for the most part.

Comment: And what if the hospital is ignoring it?  Hmm so by default if they do not have the paper they default to family members and those on your plan in my experience, so there seems to be a legal grey area.  Is there an opposite form aka opposite power of attorney to prevent this?

Comment: @William Certainly it wouldn't be the first time that an insurance company didn't follow its legal obligations. But, honestly, my impression is that insurance companies when instructed through the proper channels are quite uptight and scrupulous about such things.